# Android Location.getAccuracy() returns 1

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm trying to get my current GPS accuracy by using `Location.getAccuracy()`.  However, this is returning 1 (or sometimes 2) which doesn't seem possible.  Google maps is telling me my current location accuracy is 40 meters.

Any thoughts?

```
int accuracy = (int) loc.getAccuracy();
// This will give me accuracy = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation of getAccuracy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29):

> *Returns the accuracy of the fix in meters.*

Why doesn't it seem possible? A return-value of 1, sometimes 2 meters, is perfectly fine for GPS. With a good signal strength, and locks on multiple satellites, you can get that kind of accuracy.

(Besides, since you're casting to an `int` your flooring the value. The accuracy may actually be for instance 1.9 meters.)

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you are calling `getAccuracy()` on the LocationProvider and not the Location?  From the docs:

```
public abstract int getAccuracy ()
```

**Since: API Level 1**
Returns a constant describing horizontal accuracy of this provider. If the provider returns finer grain or exact location, `ACCURACY_FINE` is returned, otherwise if the location is only approximate then `ACCURACY_COARSE` is returned.

Where `ACCURACY_FINE` and `ACCURACY_COARSE` are defined as:

```
public static final int ACCURACY_COARSE
```

**Since: API Level 1**
A constant indicating an approximate accuracy requirement

```
Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
public static final int ACCURACY_FINE
```

**Since: API Level 1**
A constant indicating a finer location accuracy requirement

```
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

Answer (score 1):

40 meters looks more like cellular network accuracy, but not GPS.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have 6-9 satelites visible (Scandinavia) and get around 2.0 meters for getAccuracy() - and it turns out, in practice, to be around +|- 40 cm accurate in reality.